# Passing params to inner function

Tags: php, codeigniter

Why **$poll_id** param is NULL (undefined) in array_map's callback? The code below works, but I had to use special private **$id** class member to overcome it...

```
class Polls_model extends CI_Model
{

    private $id;

    // ...

    public function add_poll_answers($poll_id, $answers)
    {
        $this->id = $poll_id;

        if (count($answers) > 0)
        {
            $this->db->insert_batch('poll_answers', 
                array_map(
                    function ($a)
                    {
                        log($poll_id); // NULL, why?
                        log($this->id); // correct value
                        return ['name' => $a,'poll_id' => $this->id];
                    }, $answers));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you assign `$poll_id` to `$this->id` in your code `$this->id = $poll_id;`

Comment: actually cant understand what you doing even

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable $poll_id is null because his scope is local in the function.
You can use php closure:

```
function ($a) use ($poll_id)
{
    log($poll_id); // NULL, why?
    log($this->id); // correct value
    return ['name' => $a,'poll_id' => $this->id];
}, $answers));
```

http://php.net/manual/de/functions.anonymous.php